# Gremlin - how to ensure one vertex only have one inbound edge?

Tags: gremlin, graph-databases, amazon-neptune

I have `person` vertex and `book` vertex connected by `owns` edge (aka `person`=> `owns` => `book`). How can I ensure one `book` can only be owned by one `person`? In other words, I need a Gremlin query like `addE('owns').from(person_1).to(book_1)` only if the vertex book_1 has no inbound edge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This pattern is described in the "Element Existence" [recipe](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/recipes/#element-existence) and follows the standard `fold()/coalesce()/unfold()` pattern. Basically, you would so something like:

```
g.V('book_1_id').as('book_1').
  V('person_1_id').as('person_1').
  coalesce(outE('owns').where(outV().as('book_1')),
           addE('owns').from(`person_1`).to(`book_1`))
```

If you are using TinkerPop 3.6.x or later you might try using the `mergeE()` [step](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#mergeedge-step):

```
g.mergeE([(from):'book_id_1',(to):'book_id_1',(label):'owns'])
```